# Setting PropertyGrid.SelectedObject at runtime

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a class that looks as follows:

```
public class DashWidgetParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Type ValueType { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public DashWidgetParameter(string ParameterName, Type ParameterType, object Value)
    {
        this.Name = ParameterName;
        this.ValueType = ParameterType;
        this.Value = Value;
    }
}
```

This class is used by some other objects in my application to store their respective parameters. Each object has a line

```
List<DashWidgetParameter> Parameters = new List<DashWidgetParameter>();
```

followed by a few lines like these:

```
paramList.Add(new DashWidgetParameter("Item Type", typeof(int), 40));
paramList.Add(new DashWidgetParameter("Status Categories", typeof(List<string>), new List<string> { "New", "Configured", "Processed" }));
```

These last few lines are different for each object so I couldn't define one class with a set list of properties.

I'd like to provide a visual way for the user to be able to edit the parameter values for each of these objects and I was hoping that I could use the `PropertyGrid` control but I'm struggling to make it work.

I don't have an object that I can set the `PropertyGrid.SelectedObject` to and unsurprisingly, if I set it to `Parameters` (defined above as `List<DashWidgetParameter> Parameters`) the `PropertyGrid` contains just two properties, `Count` and `Capacity`.

Is there not a way that I can iterate through my `Parameters` list and add them one by one to the `PropertyGrid`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ParameterList {
    public List<DashWidgetParameter> Parameters { get; set; }
}

PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new ParameterList { Parameters = paramList };
```

Alternatively, you can implement a customized view (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4448/Customized-display-of-collection-data-in-a-Propert).

Comment: I don't understand how this would be a solution. If I do this then the PropertyGrid will have only a single property, called Parameters.

Comment: @DewaldSwanepoel Yes, and you will get the button (with ellipsis) to invoke the list of items. Just try and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: OK, I've tried it and it doesn't really do what I need. First of all, like I suspected, it gives a single property in the PropertyGrid with the name "Parameters". If I click on the ellipses of the (Collection) value, it brings up a collection editor showing the different properties as members and the only "property" for each member that can actually be changed is the name, not the value.

Comment: @DewaldSwanepoel I see. If it comes to your `Value` property of type `object`, then you have to use a type converter. There is no way to guess the type of the `Value`, so the edit field is disabled.